# Sysdate+days as default value in table column - Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I'm working on my table which is supposed to store data about rented cars.
And there are 3 important columns:

```
RENT_DATE DATE DEFAULT TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
DAYS NUMBER NOT NULL,
RETURN_DATE DATE DEFAULT TO_DATE(SYSDATE+DAYS, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

My problem is that RETURN_DATE column is giving me error:
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

What i want is that RENT_DATE set automatically date when record is added.
DAYS column is to store for how much days someone is renting car.
And the last column should store date of when car should be returned.

Thank you for any type of help.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you very much for this tip. Unfortunately this is how we were taught.

Comment: You can't refer to one column in the default value for another. You will either need to specify the number of days as a constant (e.g. sysdate+7), or use a PL/SQL API or trigger to modify the value of return_date as the record is being inserted.

Comment: Agree with @a_horse_with_no_name: "RENT_DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE" is all that is required. Anything else is either overkill or just plain wrong. Use of TO_DATE specifically is silly, as the field has a data type of DATE, which has no format. You are performing three calculations, two of which are totally unnecessary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then if i can ask, how should the syntax look for column with date if i want to set its format? Do I get rid of to_date, or date and keep to_date?

Comment: Set nls_date_format or use to_char in queries where you need specific format

Comment: If a column is a DATE (datatype), then you don't set it's format.  It is oracle's internal binary format. "formatting" a DATE is only to convert it to a character string so it can be read and understood by humans.   And if the column is used to store a date but not of DATE data type, then you have a serious design flaw.  For more, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/dealing-with-dates    As for " Unfortunately this is how we were taught" I'd have serious doubts about what else you were incorrectly taught.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't make sense:

```
DEFAULT TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

SYSDATE is already a date. TO_DATE requires a char, so this takes a date, Oracle implicitly turns the date into a char, and then TO_DATE converts it back to a date. This is risky/unreliable because it uses a hardcoded date format to operate on a date that has been implicitly turned to a string using the system default format, which might one day not be DD-MM-YYYY (you're building a latent bug into your software)

If you want a date without a time on it use TRUNC(SYSDATE)

---

The other problem doesn't make sense either: you're storing a number of days rented for and also the return date, when one is a function of the other. Storing redundant data becomes a headache because you have to keep them in sync. My person class stores my birthdate, and I calculate how old I am. I don't store my age too and then update my table every day/year etc

Work out which will be more beneficial to you to store, and store it, then calculate the other whenever you want it. Personally I would store the return date as it's absolute, rather than open to interpretation of "is that working days, calendar days? what about public holidays? if the start date is jan 1 and the rental is for 10 days, is the car brought back on the 10th or the 11th?"

If you're desperate to have both columns in your DB consider using a view to calculate it or a function based column (again, to calculate one from the other) so they stay in sync

All in, you could look at this:

```
create table X(
  RENT_DATE DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(SYSDATE) NOT NULL,
  RETURN_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  DAYS AS  (TRUNC(RETURN_DATE - RENT_DATE) + 1)
)
```

I put the days as +1 because to me, a car taken on the 1st and returned on the second is 2 days, but you might want to get more accurate - if it's taken on the first and returned before 10am on the second then it's one day otherwise it's 2 etc...

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try to rethink my solution.
As i said above it's how we were taught in University when setting a format for date.

Comment: Add nls_date_format in OS environment variables or use `alter session set nls_date_format =... `

Comment: In addition, you can add virtual calculated column based on those 2 columns, ie `alter table... add return_date date generated always as (rent_date + days) virtual;`

Comment: *it's how we were taught in University* - send me your supervisor's email so I can admonish them too ;) (I won't, but trust me [or anyone else who understands the power of TRUNC on a date] - if a date is a date you keep it as a date. You don't round trip it through string unless you absolutely have to, and those situations are very few and far between/this is not one of those)

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I mentioned it towards the end of the answer with "function based column" but I've added an example

Comment: "it's how we were taught in University when setting a format for date" - what you did wasn't formatting the date. All it did, effectively, was truncate the time portion out of it which would have been more easily accomplished with "TRUNC(SYSDATE)". Dates and timestamps are not stored in a formatted fashion like text; formatting is applied at the time of select, for each query, not at the time of insert.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  RENT_DATE   DATE
              DEFAULT TRUNC( SYSDATE )
              CONSTRAINT table_name__rent_date__nn NOT NULL
              CONSTRAINT table_name__rent_date_chk CHECK ( rent_date = TRUNC( rent_date ) ),
  DAYS        NUMBER
              DEFAULT 7
              CONSTRAINT table_name__days__nn NOT NULL,
  RETURN_DATE DATE
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( RENT_DATE + DAYS ) VIRTUAL
);
```

Then you can insert values:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( rent_date, days ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, DEFAULT );
INSERT INTO table_name ( rent_date, days ) VALUES ( DATE '2020-01-01', 1 );
```

And:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> RENT_DATE           | DAYS | RETURN_DATE        
> :------------------ | ---: | :------------------
> 2020-09-12T00:00:00 |    7 | 2020-09-19T00:00:00
> 2020-01-01T00:00:00 |    1 | 2020-01-02T00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0113cb6281e3b38490a85f054e0acb9e)*